Embedding Sobolev spaces.
Let $s>0$. The Bessel potential space is $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\left\{u\text{ tempered distribution }\colon \left\|u\right\|_{H^{s,p}}=\left\|\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((1+|\xi|^2)^{s/}\widehat{u}\right)\right\|_{p}<\infty\right\}$
Question 1. $0<s_1\leq s_2$ implies $H^{s_2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset H^{s_1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?
My attempt:
\begin{align}
\left\|u\right\|_{H^{s_1,p}}&=\left\|\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((1+|\xi|^2)^{s_1/2}\widehat{u}\right)\right\|_{p}\\
&=\left\|\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{(1+|\xi|^2)^{(s_2-s_1)/2}}
\mathcal{F}\left(\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((1+|\xi|^2)^{s_2/2}\widehat{u}\right)\right)\right]\right\|_{p}\\
&\leq C\left\|\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((1+|\xi|^2)^{s_2/2}\widehat{u}\right)\right\|_p\\
&=C\left\|u\right\|_{H^{s_2,p}}
\end{align}
where the inequality holds because $\frac{1}{(1+|\xi|^2)^{(s_2-s_1)/2}}$ is a Fourier multiplier for $L^p$ (because $s_2-s_1\geq 0$) (although I have not found a book where this multiplier appears. Where could I find it?)
Question 2. $0<s_1\leq s_2$ implies $H^{s_2,p}(\mathbb{T}^n)\subset H^{s_1,p}(\mathbb{T}^n)$ holds on the torus $\mathbb{T}^n$?
